# How nodejs allows for better http request performance without multithreading?

Tags: javascript, node.js, concurrency, libuv

I've been reading a lot and watching a lot of Youtube lectures on Nodejs event loop and libuv but I still can't understand a few things: as per this slide from [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sGTRmPiXD4Y) lecture from one of the people behind libuv:

[image]

http requests are handles asynchronously, that is they come into the event loop one by one and are handled pretty much in FIFO order as far as I understand as threads are not used to handle requests in parallel. But then how can Nodejs be event remotely as fast as an [equivalent](https://dzone.com/articles/performance-comparison-between) Java multi-threaded server (not to mention faster actually)? Is there something underneath libuv that runs those requests using threads?

In addition if every request goes through loop and threads are not used to process requests then what is `Promise.all` for?

Also does Javascript also use libuv or only Nodejs uses it?

Answer (score 1):

`Javascript` has only one thread, imagine running a Java `servlet container` running with one thread. Only difference is that `JS` code expects you to release the thread if you're not actively processing (Actively using CPU cycles) anything while Java will expect you to keep the thread blocked till you're ready to return the response, even if you're waiting for `IO` (ie. DB query)

So when we say that `Nodejs` is able to serve a lot of requests we mean a lot of `IO bound` requests, which most real life HTTP requests are. It can not out perform any multi threaded server in terms of serving `CPU bound` requests, which is wrong use case for `nodejs`. In case of `IO bound` requests node will just keep pushing the requests in a queue as soon as they go for `IO`. These requests have a callback method (for IO response, ie. DB query output) attached to them for certain events which is checked during event loop. So during running event loop, node can have a million requests in the queue and not be using CPU for any, if none of the events have been triggered yet. While servlet container will die before serving 1 million requests, because it won't be able to keep up with the resources needed by a million threads.

Now even `Servlet API` has `async` capabilities [request.startAsync()](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#startAsync()), which releases container thread while waiting for `IO` or any other even to occur, freeing threads to serve more requests.

Comment: Your answer didn't clear my questions: if requests are handled one by one in event loop, then what is the advantage of using `Promise.all`?Also, say we have 4 requests. In node this means that they will be executed one by one. If each request takes 500ms to get response this will take 2 seconds (under perfect conditions, e.g. node process doesn't get blocked in the middle). In Java theoretical server, 4 threads would be opened. Let's say the time needed to create a thread is 500ms. Then the execution of 4 threads in Java takes 1 second. What am I missing?

Comment: Advantage of `Promise.all` is to be able to do something when all of a set of operations completed. Promises are used just to get rid of callback chain that we get when working with Javascript, they make code more structured and easier to easier to understand, they've nothing to do with the parallelization. Concurrency that you mentioned is not dependent on the number of threads running but the number of CPU's you're running on. If Servlet container is running on a 4CPU machine it won't do more than 4 concurrent processes, even with 1000 threads.

Comment: I think OP is assuming I/O operations only file read and write operations. All the HTTP calls, setTimeout calls, DB calls all are async and these calls will be queued and executed on OS threads.